# Selenium TestSuit from Maven on xvfb

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'd like to run my Selenium TestSuite from Maven, during the Integration test phase.

I've found this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/selenium-test-automation-with-maven.html

I can start a Jetty server, before the test, start the test, and stop the Jetty. But I'd like to run the tests on Travis CI, and I've no idea, how to do this. I've found this website: http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/

So, I can start a xvfb server on any display port, I'd like. But cannot found any configuration, to start the `selenium:selenese` on that display. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xvfb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Zetten/xvfb-maven-plugin) to start xvfb before tests, run them using related `DISPLAY` environment variable, and stop xvfb after all.

It has just been release in Maven central.

Comment: I didn't test this on TravisCI, but it works in jenkins on my own CI server.